# How to accept arrays to CTE using VALUES and then insert as separate records

Tags: arrays, postgresql, common-table-expression

PostgreSQL 11.1

I would like to do something like this in PostgreSQL but do not know how to read in arrays nor how to insert from arrays. I'm stuck.

```
WITH _in (name, cash, checks) AS (
    VALUES (UPPER($1), ARRAY[]::numeric(10,2), ARRAY[]::numeric(10,2)
)
INSERT INTO payments(name, cash, checks)
SELECT n.name, n.cash, n.checks
FROM _in n;
```

That is, I need the CTE to accept array of cash and an array of checks--the cash array and the check array one-to-one with each other and match this to the single name value. Hence, I would like the INSERT INTO payments to actually do the following insertions into the payments table:

```
record 0 :   name, cash[1], check[1]
record 1 :   name, cash[2], check[2]
record 2 :   name, cash[3], check[3]
```

etc...

Can this be done?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unnest:

```
WITH _in (name, cash, checks) AS (
    VALUES (UPPER($1), ARRAY[...]::numeric(10,2)[], ARRAY[...]::numeric(10,2)[])
)
INSERT INTO payments(name, cash, checks)
SELECT n.name, unnest(n.cash), unnest(n.checks)
FROM _in n;
```

Note that you need a cast to an array `::numeric(10,2)[]` rather than to a "simple" numeric.

How exactly you have to pass that value depends on the programming language and the frameworks you use.